# Using geocomplete jquery plugin, how to limit types to airports only

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, geocoding

I want to make a simple autocomplete on an input field for my web app. I am using the geocomplete jquery plugin to do this as documented here:
http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/docs/

Everything works but I want to limit the search scope to airports only. The documentation suggests calling the function like this:

```
// doesn't work
$("input#airport").geocomplete({
 types:['airport']
});
```

Unfortunately this does not work, it doesn't return any results. However, setting this to establishments, does work. And since 'establishment' and 'airport' are in the same list of the documentation, I figured this should work..

```
// works
$("input#airport").geocomplete({
 types: ['establisment']
});
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax, did I misread the doc or is there something wrong with the plugin? Any help greatly appreciated.

You can see my implementation on this URL:
http://xqx.be/KEA-flytastic/html/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI - I found the answer. **The airport type is not supported for autocompletion** (yet). You can read this here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete

The documentation of the jQuery plugin GeoComplete did not point this out correctly.